# How to model function with unknown exponents?

Tags: exponential-function, systems-of-equations, mathematical-modeling

I know the **Cobb-Douglass** function which describes the production quantity:

$$Q(K, L) = A \cdot K^\alpha \cdot L^\beta$$

Also I do know multiple assignments of `K` (*Capital)* and `L` (*Labour*) to `Q` (*Quantity*):

```
Q | 10 | 30 | 60 | 80 | 95 | 108
K | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |  10
L |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |   6
```

Because we have three unknown variables and we have *jumps* in `Q` I decided to choose three *different* assignments:

$$Q(10, 1) = 10$$
$$Q(10, 3) = 60$$
$$Q(10, 5) = 95$$

Now when I insert the first assignment I can get the value of `A`:

$$\implies 10 = A \cdot 10^\alpha \cdot 1^\beta \iff A = \frac{10}{10^\alpha \cdot 1^\beta}$$

However when I now use the second assignment to get `⍺` or `β` I make some mistake:

$$
\implies 30 = \frac{10 \cdot 2^\alpha 10^\beta}{1^\alpha 10^\beta} \iff 3 = \frac{2^\alpha 10^\beta}{1^\alpha 10^\beta} \iff 3 = \frac{2^\alpha}{1^\alpha} \iff 3 = \frac{1^\alpha \cdot 1^\alpha}{1^\alpha} \iff 3 = 1^\alpha \iff \alpha = \frac{log(3)}{log(1)}$$

Which does not seem correct to me.

**Where did the mistake(s) occur?**

Bodo

Comment: Your mistake is in going from

$3= \frac{2^{\alpha}}{1^{\alpha}}$ to $3=\frac{1^{\alpha}\cdot1^{\alpha}}{1^{\alpha}}$

Comment: @SBareS How would that step be right? Somehow I need to simplify the $$2^\alpha \cdot 1^\alpha$$

Comment: $1^\alpha=1$ no matter what $\alpha$ is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes. First, $A=\frac{10}{10^\alpha1^\beta}=10^{1-\alpha}$ (this was correct!). But now, you use this for the second assignment, and I think you mixed up $\alpha$ and $\beta$. You should have had
$Q(10,2)=30$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $10^{1-\alpha}\cdot10^\alpha\cdot2^\beta=30$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $10\cdot 2^\beta=30$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $2^\beta=3$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\beta=\frac{\log3}{\log2}$.
There was a further mistake in your calculation: $2^\alpha\neq1^\alpha\cdot1^\alpha$!

Comment: How do you mean I mixed up $\alpha$ and $\beta$? Shouln't it make no matter how I insert it into the second assignment?

Comment: you calculated first $A=\frac{10}{10^\alpha1^\beta}$, but then you used $A=\frac{10}{10^\beta1^\alpha}$